# PHP login Mysqli Erro

Tags: php, login

Estou a desenvolver uma plataforma e na parte do *Login* estou com um problema. 
A página `index.php` tem o formulario de login(Email e senha). 
Estou com dificuldade em fazer a comparação dos dados inseridos com os dados da BD.

```
require_once 'db_connect.php';
session_start();


//$erros = array();
$email = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
$senha = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['senha']);

print_r($email);
print_r($senha);

if(!empty($email) and !empty($senha)):
    $sql = "select login from utilizador where login = '$email'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    print_r($resultado);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0):

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM utilizador WHERE login = '$email' and password = (md5('$senha'))";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
         print_r($resultado);
    endif;
```

O resultado obtido é este:

```
     admin@admin.pt1234mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 

     [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

     mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4

     [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )
```

Não estou a conseguir que o ultimo resultado seja `num_rows => 1` para continuar para o seguinte codigo.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
$dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
mysqli_close($connect);
$_SESSION['logado'] = true;
$_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dados['id'];
header('Location: home.php');
    else:
       $erros[] = "<li> Usuário e senha não conferem </li>";
           endif;
    endif;
```

Comment: Já debugou o seu código e passou o resultado diretamente no banco de dados para verificar se retorna algo?

Comment: Ao cadastrar o usuário no banco de dados, você criptografa a senha duas vezes com o *MD5*? Porque é isso que está ocorrendo no código.

Comment: o md5 foi erro meu. Está apenas uma vez no codigo . Na BD consigo ver o resultado da linha correcta

Comment: Após o $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); da ultima linha as  [num_rows] => 0

Comment: no ultimo select substitui o * pelo campos e já funcionou. Alguem me consegue explicar porque ?